# Create a new variable if value in var1 exists in var2

Tags: stata

Assume I have a `list_a` variable with all possible sports played in the world:

```
football 
tennis 
hockey
cricket
croquet
racquetball
cricket
pingpong
squash
rugby
swimming
swimming
soccer
```

Also assume I have another variable `list_b` of only three sports:

```
cricket
hockey
swimming
```

I want to create a new variable `Cont`, which will equal `1` when the sports in `list_a` are found in `list_b`, and equal to `0` when the sport is not in `list_b`.

This is what variable `Cont` would look like:

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
1 
1
0
```

Will the following work:

```
gen Cont = 0
replace Cont = 1 if  (strmatch( list_a, ( list_b)))
```

---

**EDIT:**

Suppose `list_a` also contained `hoccckey` (which is a typo) but I still want it to get counted.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As @PearlySpencer has explained `gen cont = strmatch(list_a, list_b)` (which is your code simplified down) won't work because `list_a` will only be compared with `list_b` in the same observation. Nothing makes that syntax produce a comparison across all possible pairs of values. Experiment should have shown you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no because your approach will compare the values of the two variables in each observation. Instead, you need to compare the value at each row of `list_a`, with all values of variable `list_b`.

Using your toy example:

```
clear

input strL(list_a list_b)
football cricket
tennis hockey 
hockey swimming 
cricket 
croquet 
racquetball 
cricket
pingpong
squash
rugby
swimming 
swimming
soccer
end
```

The following illustrates the philosophy:

```
local obs = _N
generate Cont = 0

forvalues i = 1 / `obs' {
    forvalues j = 1 / `obs' {
        replace Cont = 1 if list_a[`i'] == list_b[`j'] in `i'
    }
}

list
     +-------------------------------+
     |      list_a     list_b   Cont |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |    football    cricket      0 |
  2. |      tennis     hockey      0 |
  3. |      hockey   swimming      1 |
  4. |     cricket                 1 |
  5. |     croquet                 0 |
     |-------------------------------|
  6. | racquetball                 0 |
  7. |     cricket                 1 |
  8. |    pingpong                 0 |
  9. |      squash                 0 |
 10. |       rugby                 0 |
     |-------------------------------|
 11. |    swimming                 1 |
 12. |    swimming                 1 |
 13. |      soccer                 0 |
     +-------------------------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you have certain typos that you *additionally* want to take into account, you can combine my solution with @NickCox's. In the above loop use instead:

```
replace Cont = 1 if inlist(list_a, "hoccckey") | list_a[`i'] == list_b[`j'] in `i'
```

Comment: A refinement on this would be to loop over the distinct values of each variable to avoid repeating the same test. There is an overhead in finding those distinct values.

Comment: Suppose list_a also contained hoccckey (which is a typo) but I still want it to get counted. Is there a way to do that? Perhaps a matchit?

Comment: @JyothsnaHarithsa see my revised answer but in the future please start a new question.

Comment: what if we did not know what the exact typo is in a large dataset?
Suppose I want to set Cont = 1 if the entry in list_a is an 80% match to the entry in list_b?

Comment: This is an entirely different question. You need something like fuzzy matching which is really difficult.

Comment: If you can define 80% match you can probably program finding it. Otherwise there is no point to pulling numbers out of the air.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple technique that works fine for your toy example:

```
clear 
input strL list_a 
football 
tennis 
hockey
cricket
croquet
racquetball
cricket
pingpong
squash
rugby
swimming
swimming
soccer 
end 

gen wanted = inlist(list_a, "cricket", "hockey", "swimming") 

list, sepby(wanted)

     +----------------------+
     |      list_a   wanted |
     |----------------------|
  1. |    football        0 |
  2. |      tennis        0 |
     |----------------------|
  3. |      hockey        1 |
  4. |     cricket        1 |
     |----------------------|
  5. |     croquet        0 |
  6. | racquetball        0 |
     |----------------------|
  7. |     cricket        1 |
     |----------------------|
  8. |    pingpong        0 |
  9. |      squash        0 |
 10. |       rugby        0 |
     |----------------------|
 11. |    swimming        1 |
 12. |    swimming        1 |
     |----------------------|
 13. |      soccer        0 |
     +----------------------+
```

If you had many more values, you could loop over the distinct values sought, using `levelsof` if they are in a second variable, or put the candidates in a separate dataset and `merge` as explained in [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/group-characteristics-for-subsets/).

All these techniques depend on exact equality of strings, so watch out for variations between upper and lower case, leading and trailing spaces and inconsistencies in spelling.

Comment: Suppose list_a also contained hoccckey (which is a typo) but I still want it to get counted. Is there a way to do that? Perhaps a matchit?

Comment: You need different code. @Pearly Spencer is spot on here. You can enlarge the list of acceptable matches but if you relax away from exact matching, it's a different ball game.